# Trying to filter an array output with jq

Tags: arrays, json, select, jq

I have the given input as such:

```js
[{
  "ciAttributes": {
    "entries": "{\"hostname-cdc1.website.com\":[\"127.0.0.1\"],\"hostname-cdc1-extension.website.com\":[\"127.0.0.1\"]}"
  },
  "ciAttributes": {
    "entries": "{\"hostname-dfw1.website.com\":[\"127.0.0.1\"],\"hostname-dfw1-extension.website.com\":[\"127.0.0.1\"]}"
  },
  "ciAttributes": {
    "entries": "{\"hostname-cdc2.website.com\":[\"127.0.0.1\"],\"hostname-cdc2-extension.website.com\":[\"127.0.0.1\"]}"
  },
  "ciAttributes": {
    "entries": "{\"hostname-dfw2.website.com\":[\"127.0.0.1\"],\"hostname-dfw2-extension.website.com\":[\"127.0.0.1\"]}"
  },
}]
```

...and when I execute my jq with the following command (manipulating existing json):

```
jq '.[].ciAttributes.entries | fromjson | keys | [ { hostname: .[0] }] | add' | jq -s '{ instances: . }'
```

...I get this output:

```js
{
  "instances": [
    {
      "hostname": "hostname-cdc1.website.com"
    },
    {
      "hostname": "hostname-dfw1.website.com"
    },
    {
      "hostname": "hostname-cdc2.website.com"
    },
    {
      "hostname": "hostname-dfw2.website.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

**My end goal is to only extract "hostnames" that contain "cdc." I've tried playing with the json select expression but I get a syntax error so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.**

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no need to call jq more than once.

Second, because the main object does not have distinct key names, you would have to use the --stream command-line option.

Third, you could use `test` to select the hostnames of interest, especially if as seems to be the case, the criterion can most easily be expressed as a regex.

So here in a nutshell is a solution:

### Invocation

```
jq -n --stream -c -f program.jq input.json
```

### program.jq

```
{instances:
 [inputs
 | select(length==2 and (.[0][-2:] == ["ciAttributes", "entries"]))
 | .[-1]
 | fromjson
 | keys_unsorted[]
 | select(test("cdc.[.]"))]}
```